# Income Tax Conundrum

Tags: income-tax, puerto-rico

I am employed in Georgia and pay federal and GA state income taxes.  My employer has granted me the option to work from Puerto Rico about 50% of the time.  I am considering moving my family and becoming a PR resident.  Am I correct about the following:

1. I would pay PR income tax on income I earn while physically working in PR (about 50% of my salary)?
2. I would pay GA state income tax as a non-resident on income I earn while physically working in GA (about 50% of my salary)?
3. I would only pay federal income tax on income earned in GA?
4. Will my GA/Federal and PR tax brackets be based on my overall salary or only on income earned in each jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

I live in Georgia also.  As far as I know, you have to give up your Georgia domicile in order to not have to pay GA taxes anymore.  I'm not sure what that means legally speaking, so I'd definitely speak with an employment attorney in Georgia about this.

Also, the [Georgia Department of Revenue](https://dor.georgia.gov/filing-requirements) can explain it in more detail.